# Loop Slider Logo without Reseting

Tags: html, css, loops, slider

I am creating a logo slider for my project website and I want the slider not to reset and start again, but create a loop of the logos. How can I do that?

Example for now:
Start | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | Stop and Reset back to 1
(The numbers represent the logos)

Example of what I want:
Start | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
(Constantly looping with no reset)

Hope you understand my problem!

CSS:

```css
.slider789 {
    width: 2159px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
.slider789 ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    animation: cambio 60s infinite linear;
    
}
.slider789 li {
    padding:0 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
.slider789 img {
    max-width: fit-content !important;
    height: 100px;
}
@keyframes cambio {
    from {margin-left: 0%}
    to {margin-left: -100%}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider789">
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <img src="https://kelmass.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/spring-boot-logo.png" alt="">
              </li>
              <li>
                  <img src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c51f.png" alt="">
              </li>
              <li>
                  <img src="https://download.logo.wine/logo/Amazon_Web_Services/Amazon_Web_Services-Logo.wine.png" alt="">
            </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: After AWS I want Spring Boot and I want this to be an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand how it works and can remake it for yourself.

```css
:root {
  --crsl-width: 80vw;
  --crsl-height: 50vh;
  --crsl-duration: 10s;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel {
  margin: auto;
}

.carousel,
.viewport,
.item {
  width: var(--crsl-width, 400px);
  height: var(--crsl-height, 300px);
}

.viewport {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  animation: x1 var(--crsl-duration, 10s) infinite;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  animation: x2 var(--crsl-duration, 10s) infinite;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  animation: x3 var(--crsl-duration, 10s) infinite;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  animation: x4 var(--crsl-duration, 10s) infinite;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  animation: x5 var(--crsl-duration, 10s) infinite;
}

@keyframes x1 {
  0%,
  95%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  15% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), 0);
  }
  35% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), var(--crsl-height, 300px));
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), var(--crsl-height, 300px));
  }
  55 {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), var(--crsl-height, 300px));
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), var(--crsl-height, 300px));
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), 0);
  }
}

@keyframes x2 {
  0%,
  95%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-1 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  15% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(-1 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(-1 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  35% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-1 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-1 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  55% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), 0);
  }
}

@keyframes x3 {
  0%,
  95%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-1 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  15% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  35% {
    transform: translate(0px, calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(0px, calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  55% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-1 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-1 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
}

@keyframes x4 {
  0%,
  95%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  15% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-2 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  35% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  55% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
}

@keyframes x5 {
  0%,
  95%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-4 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  15% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--crsl-width, 400px)), calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  35% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-3 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  55% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-4 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(var(--crsl-width, 400px), calc(-4 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(-4 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(-4 * var(--crsl-height, 300px)));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="item" style="background-color: red"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: magenta"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort but I think you misunderstood the function I want. Take a look here: https://codepen.io/antxd/pen/gOPJpbW . You see where the logo 15 ends I want to continue with logo 1. How can I do that?

Comment: @GeorgiosKompos Well no. I understood the problem correctly. My code does not specifically solve your problem, it does show a principle that you can use to solve your problem. You just need to understand how everything works and apply it for yourself.